# How can I connect to the internet from my private subnet in AWS VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nat, vpc

I am trying to set up a VPC with public and private subnets in the us-east-1 region.

My setup is like,

1. I have 2 public subnet and 2 private subnets in the us-east-1 region.
2. The private subnets span across two AZ us-east1a & us-east1b.
3. I have a c5 instance in the public subnet of us-east-1b. This instance also has a secondary private ENI in private subnet of us-east-1b for the private instances in both my private subnet (us-east-1a & us-east-1b) to have internet access.

Below are the route tables:

1. The public subnets are associated to 1 table named external where I have 0.0.0.0 pointed to an Internet gateway.
2. The private subnets are associated to another table internal where I have 0.0.0.0 pointed to the private ENI of the public instance in public subnet of us-east-1b as I mentioned in the beginning.
3. The main route table is left alone.

The Problem:

I am able to access internet from private instances in us-east-1b but cannot access internet from private instances in us-east-1a. i.e. if I ping 8.8.8.8 or any resources outside the VPC I do not get any response from the latter.

Please let me know how I can fix this. Is it not possible to route private instances situated in a different private AZ to the internet irrespective of the AZ where the public instance and private ENI.

My references are:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#NATInstance

Comment: "pointed to the private ENI " - what do you want to achieve? Are you constricting your own NAT instances?

Comment: @Marcin I actually have a firewall with two ENI (eth0- Primary, eth1- private) and I am actually trying to reproduce this env without the actual firewall itself.
I have a public facing instance in AZ1 with two ENI and I am able to access the internet from private instances in AZ1. But I want both my private instances in AZ1 and AZ2 as well to be able to connect to the internet. So My private route table entry 0.0.0.0 points to the eth1 interface which should act as the NAT.

Comment: The only difference between private instances in AZ1 (which works) and AZ2 (which does not work) is the AZ? No difference in security groups or other networking setup?

Comment: I have only used a common SG for all and have allowed all traffic 0.0.0.0. Its just one VPC and the only difference is the AZ1 and AZ2.